# Can a tree survive if someone cuts all buds?

Tags: plant-physiology

My thought was to cut all buds of a deciduous tree at spring and see if it can survive a year and develop new buds and leaves next spring. Assuming the tree is already grown and not a sapling.

If the loss of all buds would be to fatal, how many would a tree need to recover?